# JPQL - How can i search entities for key and value (Hibernate OGM (MongoDB) - Map<String, String>)

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, jpql, hibernate-ogm

I use Hibernate OGM for MongoDB, and mapping simple ShopItem entity with Map:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = ShopItem.GET_BY_NAME,
                    query = "select items from ShopItem items where 
                    items.name=:name"),
        @NamedQuery(name = ShopItem.GET_BY_OPTION,
                query = "select items from ShopItem items 
                        join items.options map 
                where ( KEY(map) = :optionKey and map = :optionValue )")
})
@Entity
public class ShopItem {

    public static final String GET_BY_NAME = "ShopItem.getByName";
    public static final String GET_BY_OPTION = "ShopItem.getByOption";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    //...etc
}
```

This mapped good. And I tried write JPQL named queries for my ShopItemRepository. I've searched NamedQuery by field 'name' and it works fine. But I need to search by both fields 'key' and 'value' and I can't write correct JPQL for this. 
For example i have entity in db:

```
{
   "_id":"df111b8a-b831-4200-95b3-f80576cd7273",
   "name":"Example",
   "description":"My description",
   "options":
        {
            "weight":"60 kg",
            "age":"22"
        }
}
```

And i want find all entities where options have key 'age' and have value '22'.

I try to write:

```
select items from ShopItem items join items.options map where ( KEY(map) = :optionKey and map = :optionValue )
```

or

```
select items from ShopItem items join items.options map where ( KEY(map) = :optionKey and :optionValue in (VALUE(map))
```

or

```
select items from ShopItem items where ( KEY(items.options) = :optionKey and items.options = :optionValue )
```

or

```
select items from ShopItem items where ( KEY(items.options) = :optionKey and :optionValue in (VALUE(items.options))
```

And have this error

```
org/hibernate/hql/ast/origin/hql/resolve/GeneratedHQLResolver.g: node from line 1:85 no viable alternative at input '('

can't look backwards more than one token in this stream
```

My code in repo:

```
List<ShopItem> result = entityManager.createNamedQuery(ShopItem.GET_BY_OPTION, ShopItem.class)
                .setParameter("optionKey", key)
                .setParameter("optionValue", value)
                .getResultList();
```

Can you help me write correct JPQL query? And if this is not possible, then suggest how to do it another way.

I can't use Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the only way to query this case is using a native query:

```
    List<ShopItem> results = session
            .createNativeQuery( "{ 'options.Weight': '60 Kg' }", ShopItem.class )
            .getResultList();
```

You can still declare the queries using `@NamedNativeQuery` (instead of `@NamedQuery`) but parameters aren't supported for MongoDB.